# Change location of short form in acronym first use? (using acro.sty)

Tags: acronyms, acro

Given the following MWE, is there a way to change the location of the abbreviated form in first use (full), so that it does not always appear after the long form is printed?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{acro,bm}
\DeclareAcronym{rho}{
    short=$\rho$,
    long=electron charge density
}
\DeclareAcronym{grad}{
    short=$\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$,
    long=gradient of \ac{rho}
}

\begin{document}

first use of grad:
\ac{grad}

would rather have:
gradient (\acs{grad}) of \acf{rho}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If not, could there be a new set of commands to use within the `\DeclareAcronym` block? 
So the declaration could instead look like

```
\DeclareAcronym{grad}{
    short=$\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$,
    long=gradient\short of \ac{rho}
}
```

Where `\short` would be replaced with a space (note there is no space before `\short`) followed by the parenthesized short form? 
Similar commands could be added for other arguments of `\DeclareAcronym` as necessary.

Comment: This is just opinion but you're pushing the automation quite hard. In this case I'd use a combination of `\acl` and `\acs` as the sentence structure is likely to be less than optimal if you switch forms automatically.

Comment: @ChrisH You're probably right, but I see LaTeX as a programming language for documents. I know it's _just_ a typesetting language, but this is the sort of thing I _assume_ could be implemented into the `acro` package directly. I was hoping Cle­mens might notice the question and just go for it, but I'm happy for alternatives.

Comment: I could probably write something for `acronym`; in fact I've done something very similar before, though inserting the short form *in* the the long form would make it harder. What I meant was that automation is easier than writing nicely, especially taking into account the nested acronyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\DeclareAcroFirstStyle` macro could in future provide an interface to achieve this, but with the current options available to it I couldn't work something out, as it stands I could find two ways to do it but both with potential issues which interfere with other [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) features.

By utilising the `\acifused{<id>}{<true>}{<false>}` macro we can adapt the `long` entry of `\DeclareAcronym{grad}{<keys>}` to change it's appearance according to whether the acronym `rho` has been used.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem particularly easy to append text to the first appearance, instead I had to define a `first-style` which only printed the long-form and include the short-form in the long as

```
\DeclareAcroFirstStyle{conditional}{inline}{
    only-long=true
}
\DeclareAcronym{grad}{
    short=$\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$,
    long=gradient \acifused{rho}{of \ac{rho} (\acs{grad})}{(\acs{grad}) of \acl{rho} (\acs{rho})},
    first-style=conditional,
}
```

While this generates first appearances as desired, it doesn't play as nicely with `\acl{grad}`, which will still generate a bracketed short form as so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro,bm}

\DeclareAcroFirstStyle{conditional}{inline}{
only-long=true
}

\DeclareAcronym{rho}{
    short=$\rho$,
    long=electron charge density,
}
\DeclareAcronym{grad}{
    short=$\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$,
    long=gradient \acifused{rho}{of \ac{rho} (\acs{grad})}{(\acs{grad}) of \acl{rho} (\acs{rho})},
    first-style=conditional,
}
\DeclareAcronym{gradtwo}{
    short=$\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$,
    long=gradient of \acs{rho}
}

\begin{document}
\ac{grad}

\acuse{rho}
\acf{grad}

\ac{grad}

\acl{grad}

\acreset{rho}
\acl{grad}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) allows for the manual creation of `\ac`-like commands, which we can use to construct something specifically for the `grad` acronym which will manually assemble the appropriate long or short form according to whether both the `rho` and `grad` (in the code below `gradtwo`) acronyms have been used.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \acgrad {s}
{
    \acro_begin:
    \acro_reset_specials:
    \acro_check_and_mark_if:nn {#1}{gradtwo}
    \acro_if_acronym_used:nTF {gradtwo}
    {
        \acro_short:n {gradtwo}
    }{
        \acro_if_acronym_used:nTF {rho}
        {
            \acro_long:n {gradtwo}~(\acro_short:n {gradtwo})
        }{
            gradient~(\acro_short:n {gradtwo})~of~\acro_long:n {rho}~(\acro_short:n {rho})
        }
    }
    \acro_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This has the advantage of leaving the `long` version untouched, and `\acgrad` is used instead of `\ac{grad}` with minimal extra diffiulty but any of the variants to do the equivalent of `\Ac{grad}`, `\acp{grad}` etc. must be manually defined in order for them to share the appropriate first appearance.

Comparing these two strategies

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{acro,bm}

\DeclareAcroFirstStyle{conditional}{inline}{
only-long=true
}

\DeclareAcronym{rho}{
    short=$\rho$,
    long=electron charge density,
}
\DeclareAcronym{grad}{
    short=$\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$,
    long=gradient \acifused{rho}{of \ac{rho} (\acs{grad})}{(\acs{grad}) of \acl{rho} (\acs{rho})},
    first-style=conditional,
}
\DeclareAcronym{gradtwo}{
    short=$\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$,
    long=gradient of \acs{rho}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \acgrad {s}
{
    \acro_begin:
    \acro_reset_specials:
    \acro_check_and_mark_if:nn {#1}{gradtwo}
    \acro_if_acronym_used:nTF {gradtwo}
    {
        \acro_short:n {gradtwo}
    }{
        \acro_if_acronym_used:nTF {rho}
        {
            \acro_long:n {gradtwo}~(\acro_short:n {gradtwo})
        }{
            gradient~(\acro_short:n {gradtwo})~of~\acro_long:n {rho}~(\acro_short:n {rho})
        }
    }
    \acro_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ac{grad}

\acuse{rho}
\acf{grad}

\ac{grad}

%\acreset{rho}
\acl{grad}

\hrule

\acreset{rho}
\acgrad

\acreset{gradtwo}
\acgrad

\acgrad

\acl{gradtwo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solutions. This is probably the best I can hope for unless the capability is baked right into `Acro`.

Comment: @twilsonco [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) is under reasonably active development, you could always try suggesting something on the [bitbucket issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues?status=new&status=open)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Dai. I submitted a ticket to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

Since no one's provided an answer with the `acro` package, here's a solution using `glossaries-extra`. This defines a custom style `ofother` that checks if the `user1` field has been set. If it has then the value is taken as the label for the other symbol and "of ..." is done (otherwise it does nothing). This is done with the custom `\ofother` command, which takes the label as the argument:

```
\newcommand*{\ofother}[1]{%
 \ifglshasfield{user1}{#1}%
 {\space of \glsentrylong{\glscurrentfieldvalue}
  (\glsxtrshort{\glscurrentfieldvalue})}%
 {}%
}
```

The custom `ofother` style that uses this command is:

```
\newabbreviationstyle{ofother}
{%
  \renewcommand*{\CustomAbbreviationFields}{%
    name={\the\glsshorttok},
    sort={\the\glslabeltok},
    first={\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)},
    description={\the\glslongtok\protect\ofother{\the\glslabeltok}}
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\GlsXtrPostNewAbbreviation}{%
    \csdef{glsxtrpostlink\glscategorylabel}{%
      \glsxtrifwasfirstuse
      {%
        \ofother{\glslabel}%
      }%
      {}%
    }%
    \glshasattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}%
    {%
      \glssetattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}{false}%
    }%
    {}%
  }%
}
{%
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{long-short}%
}
```

This uses the post-link hook to append `\ofother{\glslabel}` after the first use.

You can set different styles according to the entry's category. For example:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[symbol]{long-short}    
\setabbreviationstyle[of]{ofother}

\newabbreviation[category=symbol]{rho}{$\rho$}{electron charge density}
\newabbreviation
 [category=of,user1=rho]
 {grad}
 {$\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$}
 {gradient}
```

However, since `\ofother` does nothing if `user1` hasn't been set, they can be given the same style with just the default `abbreviation` category:

```
\setabbreviationstyle{ofother}

\newabbreviation{rho}{$\rho$}{electron charge density}
\newabbreviation
 [user1=rho]
 {grad}
 {$\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$}
 {gradient}
```

Here's a complete document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries-extra}

\newcommand*{\ofother}[1]{%
 \ifglshasfield{user1}{#1}%
 {\space of \glsentrylong{\glscurrentfieldvalue}
  (\glsxtrshort{\glscurrentfieldvalue})}%
 {}%
}

\newabbreviationstyle{ofother}
{%
  \renewcommand*{\CustomAbbreviationFields}{%
    name={\the\glsshorttok},
    sort={\the\glslabeltok},
    first={\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)},
    description={\the\glslongtok\protect\ofother{\the\glslabeltok}}
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\GlsXtrPostNewAbbreviation}{%
    \csdef{glsxtrpostlink\glscategorylabel}{%
      \glsxtrifwasfirstuse
      {%
        \ofother{\glslabel}%
      }%
      {}%
    }%
    \glshasattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}%
    {%
      \glssetattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}{false}%
    }%
    {}%
  }%
}
{%
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{long-short}%
}

\setabbreviationstyle{ofother}

\newabbreviation{rho}{$\rho$}{electron charge density}
\newabbreviation
 [user1=rho]
 {grad}
 {$\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$}
 {gradient}

\begin{document}
First use: \ac{grad}.

Next use: \ac{grad}.

Here's \ac{rho}.

Reset all.\glsresetall

First use again: \ac{rho} and \ac{grad}.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: First use: gradient (∇ρ) of electron charge density (ρ). Next use: ∇ρ. Here’s electron charge density (ρ). Reset all. First use again: electron charge density (ρ) and gradient (∇ρ) of electron charge density (ρ).]

The first use of `grad` doesn't unset `rho`. If it needs to be unset at the same time, then this just requires a minor modification to `\ofother`:

```
\newcommand*{\ofother}[1]{%
 \ifglshasfield{user1}{#1}%
 {\space of \glsentrylong{\glscurrentfieldvalue}
  (\glsxtrshort{\glscurrentfieldvalue}\glsunset{\glscurrentfieldvalue})}%
 {}%
}
```

If you want a list of all the symbols, the simplest method is to use `\printunsrtglossary` which will list all defined entries in the order of definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries-extra}

\newcommand*{\ofother}[1]{%
 \ifglshasfield{user1}{#1}%
 {\space of \glsentrylong{\glscurrentfieldvalue}
  (\glsxtrshort{\glscurrentfieldvalue}\glsunset{\glscurrentfieldvalue})}%
 {}%
}

\newabbreviationstyle{ofother}
{%
  \renewcommand*{\CustomAbbreviationFields}{%
    name={\the\glsshorttok},
    sort={\the\glslabeltok},
    first={\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)},
    description={\the\glslongtok\protect\ofother{\the\glslabeltok}}
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\GlsXtrPostNewAbbreviation}{%
    \csdef{glsxtrpostlink\glscategorylabel}{%
      \glsxtrifwasfirstuse
      {%
        \ofother{\glslabel}%
      }%
      {}%
    }%
    \glshasattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}%
    {%
      \glssetattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}{false}%
    }%
    {}%
  }%
}
{%
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{long-short}%
}

\setabbreviationstyle{ofother}

\newabbreviation{rho}{$\rho$}{electron charge density}
\newabbreviation
 [user1=rho]
 {grad}
 {$\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$}
 {gradient}

\begin{document}
First use: \ac{grad}.

Next use: \ac{grad}.

Here's \ac{rho}.

Reset all.\glsresetall

First use again: \ac{rho} and \ac{grad}.

\printunsrtglossary[title=Symbols,nogroupskip]

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document with list of symbols]

There are [lots of predefined glossary styles](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/) if you don't like the default.

If you want to use `hyperref` make sure it's loaded before `glossaries-extra`:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries-extra}
```

(In general, `hyperref` needs to be loaded last. This is one of the few exceptions.)

If you get any "undefined control sequence errors" in the above example, check you have up-to-date versions of [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) and [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra).

Comment: Wow and thanks! That's why you're a creator and I'm just a user. I've shied away from the `glossary` because it's so incredibly feature-rich. On the other hand, I switched from `acronym` to `acro` so I could get a few more features, and now I'm wishing `acro` had more. Perhaps the time has come to simply switch to `glossary` and gain the ability to do whatever I want. _All I need to do is become as proficient in `glossary` as its creator!_

Comment: A SO sidenote: This may very well be the solution I go with. Given that, should I mark this as the answer, or should I wait for a solution using `acro` because that was the specific topic of the question?

Comment: @twilsonco You could leave it a little while longer to see if any solutions with `acro` are provided, but I think if you mark an answer you can later switch to a different one if something more appropriate turns up.

Answer (score 2):

With yesterday's update to v2.8 `acro` has the property `post` which allows to prepend something to an acronym. There is also the command `\aciffirst{true}{false}` with which you can test if the acronym is used the first time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro,bm}

\DeclareAcronym{rho}{
  short = $\rho$,
  long  = electron charge density
}
\DeclareAcronym{grad}{
  short = $\bm{\nabla}$\hspace{-1.2pt}$\bm{\rho}$,
  long  = gradient ,
  post  = \aciffirst{ of \ac{rho}}{}
}

\begin{document}

first use of grad:
\ac{grad}

\acs{grad}

\end{document}
```

[image]